# How to change DNS suffix for Nighthawk M1?

Tags: router, dhcp, netgear-router

The default DNS suffix for the Nighthawk M1 is "net" which is a bit annoying and dangerous as this could cause the computer to connect to "sqlserver.net" instead of the local computer named "sqlserver".

The DNS suffix is a DHCP option but the only things you can change through the web GUI is the subnet and DHCP pool.

How do you change the DNS suffix for the Netgear Nighthawk M1?

Comment: It's not possible. See [Nighthawk M1 (MR1100-100EUS) DNS domain suffix set... - NETGEAR Communities](https://community.netgear.com/t5/Mobile-Routers-Hotspots-Modems/Nighthawk-M1-MR1100-100EUS-DNS-domain-suffix-set-to-net/td-p/1706957)

Comment: @DavidPostill, correct. I checked the settings backup file and there's no setting for that. Only the "m1login" could be changed.

Comment: @DavidPostill: "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments."